# Is there a way to reset .bind("ended") for audio/video players in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I am very new to javascript. I have a function that activates only when some media (audio or video) is played. I use .bind("ended") to activate the function. The only problem is, after I activate the function, I would like to reset the players so that it seems as if they haven't been played before.

It is part of an experiment with a series of trials, and in each trial the answers should only be presented to participants after they have played the media. The only problem is sometimes the same media appears multiple times in different trials, so if they have played the media on a previous trial, they will see the answers immediately. I want to be able to reset the players at the end of each trial so that they are not "ended", so I don't have this problem.

```
$('#realplayer-'+trialOrder[curTrial]).bind("ended", function(){
  $('#foilplayer-'+trialOrder[curTrial]).bind("ended",showanswers)
});

$('#foilplayer-'+trialOrder[curTrial]).bind("ended", function(){
  $('#realplayer-'+trialOrder[curTrial]).bind("ended",showanswers)
});
```

Let me know if you can help!

Comment: Have you tried with `.unbind()` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that trialOrder meant something else. Deleted my previous comment

Comment: I'd keep track of each video's state (using variables) and reset that when a new trial is loaded. In the `showAnswers` function you can then check the actual state of the video first.